# I can't define a string in my C++ code in qt

Tags: c++, qt, import

My code is as follows.

```
#include "test.h"
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std::string::find;


test::test(){
    string str ("ffs test ffs");
    string str2 ("test");
    if (str.find(str2) != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "found" << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "not found" << "\n";
    }
}
```

the issue I'm having is this, when trying to define a string in the C++ file qt states "unknown type name 'string'". Also on line 4 my 'import' highlights string as if it doesn't exist, despite it being an option the editor suggests to me while I'm typing it. What am I doing wrong here? Everything I find is to try and fix issues passing stuff to QStrings and nothing related to my issue as far as I can tell. I've tried both types of importing `#include <thing>` and `#include "thing"` on all the imports it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Qt. Have you tried proper includes like `#include <string>`?

Comment: yes, ive tried it both ways round exact same error is stated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::string` instead of `string`.

```
#include "test.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

test::test(){
    std::string str ("ffs test ffs");
    std::string str2 ("test");
    if (str.find(str2) != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "found" << "\n";
    } else {
        str::cout << "not found" << "\n";
    }
}
```

Don't use `using namespace` (of course in your case, it wasn't a namespace, so that's another error), use <> for system headers.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Could you explay *why* one shouldn't use `using namespace`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2):

After inclusion of the appropriate headers `iostream`, `string` etc, you can write:

```
using std::string;
```

This will bring in only `string` from the `namespace std` into your program.
And you can do this if you want to avoid typing `std::string` everywhere. You can do this for stream objects like `cout, cin` as well.

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Scope operator :: in Your Code and Access manually to std class

```
std::string
```

it will help you !